# Joomla 3 content plugn: Foreach preg_replace $row->fulltext duplicates first string

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, foreach, joomla3.0

I am setting up a new content plugin for Joomla 3, that should replace plugin tags with html content. Everything works fine till the moment when i am preg_replace plugin tags in $row->fulltext.

Here is the plugin code

```
public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0) {
$pattern = '#\{uni\}(.*){\/uni\}#sU';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $row->fulltext, $matches,  PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

    foreach($matches[1] as $k=>$uni){

        preg_match('/\{uni-title\}(.*)[\{]/Ui', $uni, $unititle);
        preg_match('/\{uni-text\}(.*)/si', $uni, $unitext);

        $titleID = str_replace(' ', '_', trim($unititle[1]));

        $newString = '<span id="'.$titleID.'">'.$unititle[1].'</span><div class="university-info-holder"><div class="university-info"><i class="icon icon-close"></i>'.$unitext[1].'</div></div>';

        $row->fulltext = preg_replace($pattern,$newString,$row->fulltext);

    }
}
```

Any ideas, why it duplicates first found match, as many times as foreach goes?

Just to mention, if i do:

```
echo $unititle[1];
```

inside foreach, items aren't duplicated, but are rendered as it should be.

Comment: http://codepad.org/Ht1qruTf  Here is html output of $row->fulltext. 
The things that i am trying to match are li elements on line 77 and 88.

Comment: Outside Joomla, as php funciton it works fine, but inside Joomla as plugin, keeps duplicate the first mach as many times as foreach goes.

Comment: You don't want to close {uni-title} and {uni-text}? Why do you have $k?

Comment: No, i don't want to close, but i don't think that is relevant to the problem. Matching them is not the issue.

$k.. matching keys from  $matches[1] array, i guess, or to be honest, copy paste leftovers :) (i am not php expert, just follow some logic while self learning)

Comment: You are not using the $k, take it out. and just have `as $uni`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i removed it. Any ideas for the other thing?

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zGuMfM  I think this is a minimal reproducable example, does that look right?

Comment: Yes, the example seems fine, and its working. My code works too, when executing as single php file. But inside Joomla framework, does not.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is working for me, the final $text only have the first one multiple times.

Comment: Your preg_replace is replacing $pattern rather than the literal $matches[1][i].  Hence it is putting that first string in twice.

Comment: Here it is the working example as single php script out of joomla framework: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zYoct0, and there is no problem with replacing $pattern.

Comment: Ok i fixed my code to solve that but anyway can you explain to me where to find the issue in the big example (hard to read)

Comment: The big example is working? Or it is showing the problem? It's hard for me to see the problem. You are just using php here so Joomla isn't going to impact it except in terms of data provided.

Comment: There is no any issue in the big example. It works as single.php out of Joomla Framework. The issue comes when i am trying to preg_replace all matches with Content plugin. $row->fulltext = preg_replace($pattern,$newString,$row->fulltext); This line keeps duplicating first match. And that is the problem that i am trying to solve.

Comment: And that text is literally as it is stored in the database? No stripping is happening? If made an example like the one I made, without all the extra stuff, minimal example, so it is just a few charcters and one doesn't need to search around for the '{uni' s  and you dump out the full text before and after the replace are the two different?

Comment: Ok, lets do it this one.

Here is the Joomla 3 plugin https://www.dropbox.com/s/7aa1uwo52qnzhzz/livefilter.zip?dl=0

And here is text for the article
http://codepad.org/OJrg593W 

Add this article, install the plugin, and see what's not happening.

Comment: Wow all that happens for me is the the curly brackets are turned to square brackets. The three titles are different and the body text is the same I think in all three originals except the videos, which are all different.

Comment: There are four. And at my end, all 4 are as first one. And now i am confused!

Comment: Nope your brackets are still curly, but because of the font that are u using, are looking alike square. And by the screenshot, i can realize that the plugin is not activated :)

Comment: I just made localhost clean install, and here is what i get:
http://prntscr.com/8dpuvt

Comment: Hmm, then, try to replace all the ->fulltext instances to ->text.

Comment: Okay now I have repeats and at the end of each I still have {uni}.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e847ff7b3a2f621426a5  Try that

Comment: Yup! Now i can kill my self. I knew it that there is a reason why i was keeping $k variable! :) Its working, except the {/uni} that still is present at the end. But i think that is another problem, so if you want, you can post it as an answer so i can mark it as the one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the original code.

1. It should be using `$row->text` instead of `$row->fulltext`. This is because when rendering an article Joomla merges tht `introtext` and `fulltext` fields.
2. It's a mistake to use $pattern for the matching when making the substitution. That's because the $pattern matches all of the items. Instead use the `$match[0][$k]` to do the replacement.  Use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace` because now you are matching the exact string and don't need to do a regex. 
   Here's the code for the whole thing.

   class PlgContentLivefilter extends JPlugin{
       public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0) {
       return  $renderUniInfo = $this->renderUniInfo($row, $params, $page = 0);
       }

   private function renderUniInfo(&$row, &$params, $page = 0) {

   ```
       $pattern = '#\{uni\}(.*){\/uni\}#sU';

       preg_match_all($pattern, $row->text, $matches);

       foreach($matches[0] as $k=>$uni){



               preg_match('/\{uni-title\}(.*)[\{]/Ui', $uni, $unititle);
               preg_match('/\{uni-text\}(.*)/si', $uni, $unitext);

               print_r($unititle[1]);

               $title = $unititle[1];
               $text = $unitext[1];

               if (preg_match('#(?:http://)?(?:https://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com/(?:v/|embed/|watch\?v=)|youtu\.be/)([\w-]+)?#i', $unitext[1], $match)) {
                   $video_id = $match[1];
                   $video_string = '<div class="videoWrapper"><iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/'.$video_id.'?rel=0"></iframe></div>';
                   $unitext[1] = preg_replace('#(?:http://)?(?:https://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com/(?:v/|embed/|watch\?v=)|youtu\.be/)([\w-]+)?#i', $video_string, $unitext[1]);
                   $text = $unitext[1];
               }

               $titleID = str_replace(' ', '_', trim($title));

               $newString = '<span id="'.$titleID.'">'.$title.'</span><div class="university-info-holder"><div class="university-info"><i class="icon icon-close"></i>'.$text.'</div></div>';


               $row->text = str_replace($matches[0][$k],$newString,$row->text);


       }

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: About the first point: At my end, with ->text does not work at all, so that's why i am using ->fulltext

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with the order the plugins are running in? Because part of what the content plugins are doing is managing the readmore and pagebreak html.